# Google App Engine with Java. Can't start:(

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a problem with GAE.

Even simpliest 'helloworld' app doesn't work in Eclipse.

Such error appears:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SecurityManagerInstaller must be loaded in the system ClassLoader; was sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@35ce36
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller.generatePolicyFile(SecurityManagerInstaller.java:103)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller.install(SecurityManagerInstaller.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:72)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:38)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:153)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
```

What does it mean, any idea, please?:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ruled out your local JVM settings by create a simple project and trying to run it?

What it means is that GAE or something you have written deployed to your local GAE instance is trying to load an invalid ClassLoader or a third party jar.

It could also mean you are trying to run one of the unavailable Java APIs like Threads, File I/O or others (see docs)